# Picard group of a normal conical affine variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, picard-group

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n_{k}$ be a conical closed subvariety. In other words,
$\mathcal{O}(X)=k[x_1,\cdots, x_n]/I$, where $I$ is generated by homogeneous polynomials. Assume also that $X$ is a normal variety. In this general setting, is there anything known about the Picard group of $X$? For example, is it always true that
the Picard group of $X$ is trivial? (This is my naive hope.)

Comment: The *class group* of $X$ (which is equal to its Picard group if $X$ is locally factorial) is described precisely in Hartshorne, Exercise II.6.3 — it is far from trivial.

Comment: But $Pic(X)$ still can be trivial even though $cl(X)$ isn't, right?

Comment: @abx: I guess a cone is very rarely locally factorial, isn't it?

Comment: @Sasha: Well, I am not sure how rare it is (I am definitely not an expert). The cone over a smooth complete intersection of dimension $\geq 3$, or over a Grassmanian, is locally factorial (but the Picard group is indeed trivial in those cases).

Comment: @abx: Let $\tilde{X}$ be the blowup of the cone $X$ at the vertex. Then the exceptional divisor is isomorphic to the base of the cone, the pullback map $\mathrm{Pic}(X) \to \mathrm{Pic}(\tilde{X})$ is injective and its image is contained in the subgroup of line bundles trivial on the exceptional divisor. On the other hand, the projection from $\tilde{X}$ to the base of the cone is the total space of a line bundle, hence this subgroup is trivial. I think this proves that $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ is trivial for any affine cone.

Comment: @Sasha: Right, very nice! I think you should write this as an answer.

Comment: Now I posted it. @abx: thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the affine cone over a normal projective variety $Y$.
Let
$$
\pi \colon \tilde{X} \to X
$$
be the blowup of $X$ at the vertex. Then $\tilde{X}$ comes with a projection
$$
p \colon \tilde{X} \to Y
$$
that identifies $\tilde{X}$ with the total space of a line bundle on $Y$ (the restriction to $Y$ of the tautological bundle from the ambient projective space). Moreover, the zero section of this line bundle coincides with the exceptional divisor $E \subset \tilde{X}$ of the blowup; in particular, $p \colon E \to Y$ is an isomorphism.

Now, the pullback map
$$
\pi^* \colon \mathrm{Pic}(X) \to \mathrm{Pic}(\tilde{X})
$$
is injective and its image is contained in the subgroup
$$
\{ L \in \mathrm{Pic}(\tilde{X}) \mid L\vert_E \cong \mathcal{O}_E \}.
\tag{*}
$$
On the other hand, the map
$$
p^* \colon \mathrm{Pic}(Y) \to \mathrm{Pic}(\tilde{X})
$$
is an isomorphism, and since the composition of $p^*$ and the restriction to $E$ is an isomorphism, it follows that the subgroup $(*)$ is zero,
hence $\mathrm{Pic}(X) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!